# VSCODE extension get all package json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

is there a way for a given workspace folders (VsCode) to get **all** the `package.json` data ?

For example if user open multiple project view and all the projects are of type nodejs
is there any api which can run on those projects and get all the package.json, or any other efficient  way ?

**Or some efficient way to get multi projects package json ?**

Comment: what do you want to do with these files. You can traverse the `workspace` list and read the files, all inside an extension

Comment: @rioV8 - I need to get the data from the package json like the list of dependencies etc

Comment: are you making an extension or asking about if an extension exists? a simple `require('./package.json')` comes to mind, its only json after all

Comment: CTRL-p. Type `package.json`

Comment: @madflow - sorry what do you mean?